# Does my motherboard supports NVME SSD or SATA ssd

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata

I plan to purchase onboard SSD, but I am not sure whether my board supports M.2 SSD 6Gbps SATA or NVME logical intefaces. Below is the specification of my motherboard.
Board Name: Gigabyte GA-A320M-S2H (rev. 1.x)
Mother Board official Website: https://www.gigabyte.com/in/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x#kf

If the board supports NVME, then can I install OS on it? Also, please suggest the best 250 GB NVME SSD for the board.

Comment: “Ultra-Fast PCIe Gen3 x4 M.2 with PCIe NVMe & SATA mode support” - What research did you do before you asked this question?  Hardware recommendations are explicitly stated in the help center to be out of scope here at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

[First of all the onboard SSD you're describing is called M.2 which is the standard for its physical size (or its physical slot/interface). The 4-digit numbers indicate its physical size in MM, ex: 2280 means its 22mm wide & 80mm long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2).

M.2 SSD's can logically use SATA, PCIe AHCI/SATA, or PCIe NVMe. pg15 of your motherboard manual (seen below) SEEMS to indicate only SATA or PCIe AHCI/SATA may be used DEPENDING ON WHICH PROCESSOR/CPU YOU USE. So I am not 100% sure if NVMe will work...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every board with NVMe from at least the past 5 years can boot from it.

Your own [manual](https://www.gigabyte.com/in/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x/support#support-manual) places no restriction on its use.